# possible alternative for "she doesn't want me to see the kids"

Tags: sentence-construction, alternatives

For the sentence:

> She doesn't want me to see the kids

Is this form correct too? :

> she wants me don't see the kids

Any difference or preference?

Thanks

Comment: Ah, but your alternative doesn't work. You can't get three verbs in the second form of the sentence, no matter how hard you try. :)

Comment: @MARamezani Why wouldn't you just take `don't` with the `see` verb? It would belong to me then, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second phrase is not grammatical. "She wants me" needs an indirect object (it is what she wants, after all). "don't see the kids" is a standalone phrase.

So when you say **she wants me** you expect **to...** after that. From what I think you are trying to say, you could go with:

> She wants me **to not** see the kids.

or closer to your example:

> She **doesn't** want me **to see** the kids.

Comment: Thanks. I see. So is it identical to the first sentence, you know, as use case or meaning?

Comment: Yes they basically mean the same thing in this context. Please check my edit.